Dynamic import of package in my NPM library
Hej. I have dynamic import of animation library lottie in my component like:
            const { default: lottie } = await import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "lottie-web" */ "lottie-web/build/player/lottie_light"
            );

Now, when I build this package and install it in my project I have to do explicit import
import "@my-package/dist/lottie-web";

to make animations work.
Is it possible in webpack/npm to replace this dynamic path after build with for example to just "lottie" and during install @my-package install also lottie in particular version to have behavior that this dynamic import imports installed package, not built file from dist?
